# c# How to show a popup with an <a> to confirm they want to perform the asp-action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

So i have this a tag and this deletes an event now i want it to show a popup to make sure that they actually want to delete it. 
this is my  tag

```
<a asp-area="User" asp-controller="MyEvent" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.EvenementId" class="btn mijnevent-btn btn-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
```

This is the action that's happening

```
var eventToDelete = _context.Evenementen.Where(me => me.EvenementId == id).SingleOrDefault(); //vind het event
            _context.Evenementen.Remove(eventToDelete); //verwijdert het event
            _context.SaveChanges(); //saved alles

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't call mvc action directly in your link due to security risks.

with your `mijnevent-btn` class in your a tag.

```
<a class="btn mijnevent-btn btn-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
```

now you can access it with jquery, get confirmation by `confirm` javascript function and `$.post` send request to delete item

```
$(document).on("click", ".mijnevent-btn", function () {
    if (confirm("are you sure you want to delete this item?")) {
        $.post("/User/MyEvent/Delete", function (data, status) {
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        })
    }
}
```

and in your action change return type

```
return Ok("Deleted!");
```

you can use [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) library to use better user interface for your alerts

Comment: why security risk ? a redirect to action starts a new request, and that would check all the permissions for the new Action before, and reject the user if he has not the required permissions.

Comment: call action in a tag raise action with `HttpGet` method then with small mistake all users can delete items easily. delete action should call in `HttpPost` or `HttpDelete` methods.

Comment: i changed everything as you said but i just added the bit of js in the <script> tag and now the button isn't working

Comment: code updated! you should add jquery library before script. in `$.post` method call action with path `@Url.Action("Delete", "MyEvent", new { area = "User" })` or static string like `"/User/MyEvent/Delete"` don't forget to change delete action to `HttpPost`

Comment: Still not working on the last two } it also says (js) ',' expected and on the second one it says (js) Declaration or statement expected

Comment: sorry bother you, I forgot to close `$.post` method after done

Comment: I just tried to do it and set a breakpoint and it says that it won't be hit so i can't acces the script

Comment: It is so strange!!!, codes are really clear and i used thousand times. one way you can add javascript error notifier ads on to your browser to find exact problem in client side

Comment: I just got a Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at the $(document)

Comment: I said before it seems jquery not added to your page correctly. use cdn version `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` or local version

Comment: I added that as well to the script tag and now i dont get the reference error anymore but it still says the code is unreachable

Comment: add `console.log()` to every line of your java-script codes and break-point beginning of your c# action to realize when error occurred